# Get generic type of static class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have generic static class:

```
 public static class IsolatedStorageCacheManager<BagType>
 {
 }
```

and method:

```
       public static BagType Retrieve()
    {
        BagType obj = default(BagType);
        try
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile appStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            string fileName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.xml", obj.GetType().Name);
            if (appStore.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, appStore))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(isoStream))
                    {
                        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                        obj = (BagType)x.Deserialize(sr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

How can I get specific type send as BagType in Retrive method? I try using reflection but no result ;/

Comment: This question is worded in a confusing way. The generic type is always `BagType` in your code. You don't really need reflection here because it is hard-coded to `BagType`.

Comment: you should show the code you try to use reflection, you question is kind of vague to answer

Comment: I dont see reflection in here, what exception you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but does this help?

```
public static class IsolatedStorageCacheManager<BagType>
{
    public static Type Retrieve()
    {
        return typeof(BagType);
    }
}
```